# Jest genMockFromModule named exports

Tags: javascript, jestjs

According to the jest docs, it's a good idea to use `genMockFromModule` and then mock specific methods to your needs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestgenmockfrommodulemodulename

This works for default exports, but how do you use this with named exports?

I tried doing this:

```
const matches = jest.genMockFromModule("../matches");

matches.index = jest.fn();

export {
  ...matches
}
```

But you can't use a spread operator when exporting methods.

Doing this:

```
const matches = jest.genMockFromModule("../matches");

matches.index = jest.fn();

export matches
```

Also doesn't work because it expects a declaration…

Am I missing something?

**Edit: Add matches.js example code**

An example of code inside `matches.js` (the file I'm trying to mock):

```
import { dwf_api_endpoint } from "../config/api";
import Client from "./Client";

export const index = (): Promise<Object> =>
  Client.get(`${dwf_api_endpoint}/matches`);

export const show = (id: number, ws: boolean): Promise<Object> =>
  Client.get(`${dwf_api_endpoint}/matches/${id}${ws ? "?ws=1" : ""}`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just had to use `module.exports`:

```
const matches = jest.genMockFromModule("../matches.js");

matches.index = jest.fn();

module.exports = matches;
```